# rangeOfString doesn´t recognize Substring

Tags: objective-c

I have this behaviour I can´t understand.

```
NSString *title = [[PushNotifcationManager getPushNotificationSettingsForKey:@"settings"] objectForKey:@"title"];
NSLog(@"title: %@",title); //Outputs Test\ntest
if([title rangeOfString:@"\n"].location == NSNotFound){
   //String contains no \n
}else{
   //String contains \n
}
```

Even though the String clearly contains "\n" the `[title rangeOfString:@"\n"].location == NSNotFound` returns `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSLog("%@")` does not escape backslash characters in strings, so the output
`Test\ntest` means that your string contains a backslash character followed by a `n`,
not a newline character.

Therefore you have to check for

```
[title rangeOfString:@"\\n"]
```

where `\\` in a string literal stands for one backslash character.